# WooCommerce - Como ativar classe de imposto de “taxa zero” para um tipo de usuário e para uma categoria específica?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

No site WooCommerce que estou a desenvolver, estarei a vender não só para o cliente final, mas também para revendedores. O problema é que os revendedores estão isentos de IMPOSTOS e, portanto, preciso de uma função personalizada para ativar a taxa de imposto zero para certos tipo de utilizador.

Portanto, o meu problema é que o código que tenho funciona perfeitamente (quando o usuário é administrador ou revendedor), mas não sei como fazer para que estas alterações se reflitam apenas numa categoria de produto (vinho).

Aqui está o código que estou a usar:

```
function wc_diff_rate_for_user( $tax_class, $product ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_data = get_userdata($current_user->ID);

    if ( in_array( 'administrator', $current_user_data->roles ) || in_array( 'reseller', $current_user_data->roles ) )
        $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';

    return $tax_class;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 10, 2 );
```

Como posso fazer para que isto funcione somente numa categoria de produto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar `$product->get_categories()` para listar as categorias do produto.

Assim você pode checar se o produto está ou não incluído na categoria desejada, e criar uma nova condicional, assim como você fez para as roles de usuário.